# Installing pygame mac, python 2.7.9, issues with freetype and other dependencies

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame on Mac, and I've been able to install the dependencies, however I'm stuck at this step

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

The installation fails at the certain point:

```
fatal error: 'freetype/config/ftheader.h' file not found

#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>
```

How do I fix this, I'm pretty sure I have freetype (see below)?

I also noticed that even though I installed all the dependencies, I get notifications like these when compiling.

```
SDL     : found 1.2.15
Framework SDL not found
FONT    : found
Framework SDL_ttf not found
IMAGE   : found
Framework SDL_image not found
MIXER   : found
Framework SDL_mixer not found
SMPEG   : found 0.4.5
Framework smpeg not found
Framework CoreMIDI found
Framework QuickTime found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
PORTMIDI: found
FREETYPE: found 2.5.3
AVFORMAT: not found
SWSCALE : not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and the following worked for me:

First, find the location of your systems freetype include files with

```
freetype-config --cflags
```

For me, the first result looked like:

```
-I/Users/username/anaconda/include/freetype2
```

Now rerun the `pip install` but with the environment variable `CFLAGS` set to result of the previous step. Again, for me, this looked like:

```
CFLAGS='-I/Users/username/anaconda/include/freetype2 pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```